# Выравнивание текста разных размеров

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Столкнулся с задачей: выровнять текст, чтобы отступы слева были одинаковые, при разных размерах текста. Естественно, это можно сделать с помощью отступов, попиксельно подобрать отступ, но хотелось бы узнать возможно ли сделать как-то лучше и красивее. Ниже пример, где явно видно, что у "ППП" отступ больше, чем у "ННН".

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400');

div {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.first {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.second {
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="first">ННН</div>
  <div class="second">ППП</div>
</div>
```

Comment: или как вариант не задавать свойство font-family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя.

Можно разве что через `text-indent` , но также придется задавать как padding, разницы нет. Разве что по семантике будет правильнее.

Comment: Спасибо, если через часок не будет других ответов - помечу как верный

Answer (score 2):

Такое решение когда-то видел на css-tricks

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400');
article {
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.f1 {
  font-size: 3em;
}
.f2 {
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="f1">text-indent: 2em</div>
  <div class="f2">text-indent: 5em</div>
</article>
```